# Getting ModuleLoadException (C++ Modules) and TypeLoadException from WindowsBase.DLL ONLY when attempting to use the System.Windows.Clipboard class?

Tags: c#, dll, automation, clipboard

I am running a **C# WinForms app**. The goal of this small section of code is to copy the contents of a .JMP file into a .csv file for data manipulation. Easy enough right? I do not want to do this all in JMP or using a .jsl. The code for parsing and reformatting the data is already there for .csv files and has been working flawlessly.

The app that runs fine unless I have this one specific line that accesses the System.Windows.Clipboard class in my code:

`Clipboard.SetDataObject(my data);`

When I run the code with the line commented out all is well, but when I run them with the line included the app immediately goes into breakmode with these exceptions:

`System.TypeInitializationException`
`HResult=0x80131534`
`Message=The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.`
`Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>`
`StackTrace: Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace`

`Inner Exception 1:`
`ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization.`

`Inner Exception 2:`
`TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwarenessAttribute' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

For Inner Exception 1, I am confused because this is a C# app in WinForms with no C++, don't know what the deal is here.

For Inner Exception 2, I am confused because the Assembly WindowsBase is for WPF and not WinForms. I am unable to even add a project reference to this WindowsBase assembly. Again, these errors only happen when I try to do anything with the System.Windows.Clipboard class.

**I have downloaded, installed, and ensured the proper location of the following DLLs:**

**1. PresentationCore.dll**

**2. System.Windows.Forms.dll**

Am I still missing some DLLs? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead of `System.Windows.Clipboard`, for the latter one is from WPF. You should remove the reference to PresentationCore.dll, because it's from WPF and not needed in WinForm.

Comment: Oh goodness. Thanks @Ken Hung Had a feeling I was overlooking something simple